# Adding Dialogs Plugin to phonegap project prevents deviceReady from Firing

Tags: android, cordova

I started using phonegap but as a beginner i ran into many problems. 
one of the latest is problem with adding plugins 
I added plugin of dialogs

`org.apache.cordova.dialogs`

with command line tool and it added successfully . but after running application in android emulator it never fire deviceReady Event. before adding plugin it was OK.
as a note I should say I installed older versions of plugin but they didn't work either !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer , I was building my project with phonegap but installed cordova plugins , I create a new project with command

```
cordova create project [folder name] [namespace "like com.example.appname"] 
[project name]
```

and it worked correctly after that and I installed plugins as usual .